# pass variable through unobtrusive JavaScript

Tags: unobtrusive-javascript

I would like to pass variable from a button to an event handler, but I don't know how what's the right way to do that. Both line x and line y are no good. But I need something like that.

in html head

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var myButton = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

    for (var i = 0; i < myButton.length; i++)
    {
        myButton[i].onclick = function()        // <-- line x
        {                
            alert(myButton[i].data1);           // <-- line y
        }
    }
}
```

in html body

```
<button type = "button" data1 = "John" data2 = "52">Click Me</button>
<button type = "button" data1 = "Peter" data2 = "26">Click Me</button>
<button type = "button" data1 = "Mary" data2 = "44">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this JSFiddle example I just put together: http://jsfiddle.net/BshLK/1/

The problem with your code sample is that `i` is undefined by the time your event handler runs as it's only has it's value whilst the loop is running. To correct it, firstly you need to access the element you've called the event on and secondly you need to get use `getAttribute()` to get the attribute value.

Answer (score 1):

From your onload event I'm guessing you're not using jquery, but if you don't mind jquery I'd take a look at the data() method. You can do things like

```
$(function(){
    $("#button1").data("name", "value"); //your example would pass ("data","abcdefg");
    //Click handler.
    $("#button1").click(function(o,e){
         alert(o.data("name")); // alerts out "value"
    }
}
```

Then you can access that data using a selector to that element.

[Link to the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

Comment: Because, of course, jQuery is the answer to everything. You couldn't *possibly* just use `setAttribute("data-name","value")` and `getAttribute("data-name")`. Two functions in one head? Nobody can work at that speed!

Comment: @Kolkink - Honestly, I learned jQuery before I learned javascript. (it's possible!) and I just move to those methods by default. I didn't even know about the get/set attribute methods. Thanks for learnin' me though :D

Comment: Yes, well... I'm firmly of the opinion that jQuery should only be used by people who already know JavaScript. Of course, once you know JavaScript then you know that you don't *need* jQuery (you write your own functions) and therefore jQuery shouldn't even exist.

Comment: Everyone has their own hammer. :)

Comment: Yup. Mine just happens to be one I hand-crafted from wood I cut and metal I forged, rather than just going to the local WalMart XD

Comment: I'm sure your hand-crafted hammer is awesome! The fact remains that you can still go to Wal-Mart and get a jQuery one for the software-cost equivalent of $3.99, and anyone who's ever done anything will know exactly how it works. It will drive any brand of nail without bothering the user with details about specific brands. You even get free upgrades!

Comment: And I can't let your comment slide about how "jQuery shouldn't event exist"... that's just nonsense! How can you insist that helper libraries are bad? Do you go bitbanging the NIC every time you need to send a packet? No, you use convenient layers of abstraction!

Bad code can be written in any language, and by extension, with any library. jQuery helps people code faster and more effectively. You don't have to use it, of course, but it isn't *evil*! While you're carving your hammer, MrLeap is busy building houses.

Comment: FWIW, I agree that a jQuery answer oughtn't be posted unless it's either solicited or obviously necessary, but the sarcastic reply was hardly necessary.